# Comparing two arrays for same values (and position)?

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to get this "mastermind-game" working for hours now, but even `array_intersect` won't work properly and I'll just receive the first array as new array.

My two goals are:

1. Amount of correct positions
2. Amount of correct numbers

Code:

```
    <?php
        $counter = $_POST['counter'];
        $eins = $_POST['eins'];
        $zwei = $_POST['zwei'];
        $drei = $_POST['drei'];
        $vier = $_POST['vier'];
        $fuenf = $_POST['fuenf'];

        if($counter > 0){
            $elf = $_POST['elf'];
            $zwoelf = $_POST['zwoelf'];
            $dreizehn = $_POST['dreizehn'];
            $vierzehn = $_POST['vierzehn'];
            $fuenfzehn = $_POST['fuenfzehn'];
        }
        else{
            $elf = 0;
            $zwoelf = 0;
            $dreizehn = 0;
            $vierzehn = 0;
            $fuenfzehn = 0;
        }

        $inputeins[0] = $eins;
        $inputeins[1] = $zwei;
        $inputeins[2] = $drei;
        $inputeins[3] = $vier;
        $inputeins[4] = $fuenf;
        $inputdrei[0] = $elf;
        $inputdrei[1] = $zwoelf;
        $inputdrei[2] = $dreizehn;
        $inputdrei[3] = $vierzehn;
        $inputdrei[4] = $fuenfzehn;

        if($inputeins == $inputdrei){
            echo "<br><a href='ratespiel.html' style='font-size:100px;'>Gewonnen!</a>"; 
        }
        else{
            if($counter < 12){
                echo "<form action='ratespielzwei.php' method='post'>";
                echo "Ziffern von Spieler 2:<br><br>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='counter' value='$counter' hidden>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='eins' value='$eins' hidden>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='zwei' value='$zwei' hidden>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='drei' value='$drei' hidden>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='vier' value='$vier' hidden>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='fuenf' value='$fuenf' hidden>";
                echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='sechs' style='width:30px;' required> ";
                echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='sieben' style='width:30px;' required> ";
                echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='acht' style='width:30px;' required> ";
                echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='neun' style='width:30px;' required> ";
                echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='zehn' style='width:30px;' required> ";
                echo "<input type='submit' min='1' max='5' name='submitzwei' value='OK'><br><br>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<br><a href='ratespiel.html' style='font-size:100px;'>Verloren!</a>";
            }
        }

        if($counter > 0){
            foreach ($inputdrei as $ausgabe){
                echo "$ausgabe ";
            }

        }
    ?>
```

and

```
    <?php
        $counter = $_POST['counter'];
        $i = $counter + 1;
        $eins = $_POST['eins'];
        $zwei = $_POST['zwei'];
        $drei = $_POST['drei'];
        $vier = $_POST['vier'];
        $fuenf = $_POST['fuenf'];
        $sechs = $_POST['sechs'];
        $sieben = $_POST['sieben'];
        $acht = $_POST['acht'];
        $neun = $_POST['neun'];
        $zehn = $_POST['zehn'];

        $inputeins[0] = $eins;
        $inputeins[1] = $zwei;
        $inputeins[2] = $drei;
        $inputeins[3] = $vier;
        $inputeins[4] = $fuenf;
        $inputzwei[0] = $sechs;
        $inputzwei[1] = $sieben;
        $inputzwei[2] = $acht;
        $inputzwei[3] = $neun;
        $inputzwei[4] = $zehn;

        while($counter <= $i){
            $counter++;
        }

        if($inputeins == $inputzwei){
            echo "<br><a href='ratespiel.html' style='font-size:100px;'>Gewonnen!</a>"; 
        }
        else{
            echo "<form action='ratespieleins.php' method='post'>";
            echo "Ziffern von Spieler 2:<br><br>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='counter' value='$counter' hidden>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='eins' value='$eins' hidden>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='zwei' value='$zwei' hidden>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='drei' value='$drei' hidden>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='vier' value='$vier' hidden>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='fuenf' value='$fuenf' hidden>";
            echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='elf' style='width:30px;' required> ";
            echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='zwoelf' style='width:30px;' required> ";
            echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='dreizehn' style='width:30px;' required> ";
            echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='vierzehn' style='width:30px;' required>  ";
            echo "<input type='number' min='1' max='5' name='fuenfzehn' style='width:30px;' required> ";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submitdrei' value='OK'><br><br>";
            echo "</form>";
        }

        foreach ($inputzwei as $ausgabe){
            echo "$ausgabe ";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example, so we could see your problem without studying the entire code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I´m still a newb, but I added an example. To be honest, I have no clue how to achieve my two goals.

Comment: Please don't post your solution inside the question. Create your own answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the value as well as the key (index), you can use [array_intersect_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php).

Comment: Okay, this seems to work, now I have to find out how to use these Informations correctly. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goals with `array_intersect_assoc`:

```
$intersectnumbers = array_intersect($inputeins, $inputdrei);
$intersectunique = array_unique($intersectnumbers);
echo "<p>Anzahl richtiger Ziffern: " . count($intersectunique) . "</p>";

$intersectposition = array_intersect_assoc($inputeins, $inputdrei);
echo "<p>Anzahl richtiger Positionen: " . count($intersectposition) . "</p>";
```